# Hiding value from DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've built a program that creates employee schedules and assigns employees to those schedules. I can assign the schedule with no issues, but I'm having problems figuring out how to make that schedule disappear from the dropdown list if it's already been assigned to an employee so that the same schedule isn't given to two employees.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationUser.ScheduleSum, new SelectList(Model.ScheduleBuilderList, "ScheduleSummary", "ScheduleSummary"), "Choose a schedule", new {@class = "form-control"}
```

How can I get a schedule ID to disappear when assigned and reappeared if not assigned?

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Schedule Model

```
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ScheduleId { get; set; }

        public string DaysMatching { get; set; }

        public string Days { get; set; }

        public string ScheduleSummary { get; set; }

        public string MondaySchedule { get; set; }

        public string TuesdaySchedule { get; set; }

        public string WednesdaySchedule { get; set; }

        public string ThursdaySchedule { get; set; }

        public string FridaySchedule { get; set; }

        public string SaturdaySchedule { get; set; }

        public string SundaySchedule { get; set; }

        public string MondayStartTime { get; set; }

        public string TuesdayStartTime { get; set; }

        public string WednesdayStartTime { get; set; }

        public string ThursdayStartTime { get; set; }

        public string FridayStartTime { get; set; }

        public string SaturdayStartTime { get; set; }

        public string SundayStartTime { get; set; }

        public string MondayEndTime { get; set; }

        public string TuesdayEndTime { get; set; }

        public string WednesdayEndTime { get; set; }

        public string ThursdayEndTime { get; set; }

        public string FridayEndTime { get; set; }

        public string SaturdayEndTime { get; set; }

        public string SundayEndTime { get; set; }

        public string MondayFirstBreak { get; set; }

        public string TuesdayFirstBreak { get; set; }

        public string WednesdayFirstBreak { get; set; }

        public string ThursdayFirstBreak { get; set; }

        public string FridayFirstBreak { get; set; }

        public string SaturdayFirstBreak { get; set; }

        public string SundayFirstBreak { get; set; }

        public string MondaySecondBreak { get; set; }

        public string TuesdaySecondBreak { get; set; }

        public string WednesdaySecondBreak { get; set; }

        public string ThursdaySecondBreak { get; set; }

        public string FridaySecondBreak { get; set; }

        public string SaturdaySecondBreak { get; set; }

        public string SundaySecondBreak { get; set; }

        public string MondayLunch { get; set; }

        public string TuesdayLunch { get; set; }

        public string WednesdayLunch { get; set; }

        public string ThursdayLunch { get; set; }

        public string FridayLunch { get; set; }

        public string SaturdayLunch { get; set; }

        public string SundayLunch { get; set; }
```

Employee Model

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int ScheduleId { get; set; }

        public ScheduleBuilder ScheduleBuilder { get; set; }

        public string ScheduleSum { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-]([0-9]{3})[-]([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct format with hyphens. i.e. 407-200-2000")]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a valid Email")]
        public string EmailAccount => Email;
    }
```

Schedule Controller Save ActionResult

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(ScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new TierViewModel()
            {
                ScheduleBuilder = scheduleBuilder

            };
            return View("ScheduleBuilder", viewModel);
        }

        if (scheduleBuilder.Id == 0)
        {
            _context.ScheduleBuilder.Add(scheduleBuilder);

            if (scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != null)
            {
                scheduleBuilder.MondaySchedule = "Mon";
            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != null)
            {
                scheduleBuilder.TuesdaySchedule = "Tue";
            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != null)
            {
                scheduleBuilder.WednesdaySchedule = "Wed";
            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != null)
            {
                scheduleBuilder.ThursdaySchedule = "Thur";
            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != null)
            {
                scheduleBuilder.FridaySchedule = "Fri";
            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime != null)
            {
                scheduleBuilder.SaturdaySchedule = "Sat";
            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != null)
            {
                scheduleBuilder.SundaySchedule = "Sun";
            }

            scheduleBuilder.Days = scheduleBuilder.SundaySchedule + " " +
                                   scheduleBuilder.MondaySchedule + " " +
                                   scheduleBuilder.TuesdaySchedule + " " +
                                   scheduleBuilder.WednesdaySchedule + " " +
                                   scheduleBuilder.ThursdaySchedule + " " +
                                   scheduleBuilder.FridaySchedule + " " +
                                   scheduleBuilder.SaturdaySchedule;

            scheduleBuilder.DaysMatching = "Yes";

            var startTime = scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime + "-" + scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime;
            if (scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime == null)
            {
                startTime = scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime + "-" + scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime;

            }
            if (scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime == null)
            {
                startTime = scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime + "-" + scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime;

            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime == null)
            {
                startTime = scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime + "-" + scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime; ;

            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime == null)
            {
                startTime = scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime + "-" + scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime; ;

            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime == null)
            {
                startTime = scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime + "-" + scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime; ;

            }

            if (scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime == null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime == null)
            {
                startTime = scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime + "-" + scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime; ;

            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Monday End Time: " + scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Sunday End Time: " + scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime);

            if (scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != null
                ||  scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime != null

                || scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime != null

                || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime != null


                || scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != null &&  scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != null  || scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime != null

                || scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime != null
                || scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime != null

                || scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime != null &&  scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime != null || scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime != scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime && scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime != null && scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime != null

                )
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Tuesday and Sunday Don't Match!");
                scheduleBuilder.DaysMatching = "No";
            }

            scheduleBuilder.ScheduleSummary = scheduleBuilder.Days + " " + startTime + " | Scheduled Days Match: " + scheduleBuilder.DaysMatching;

        }
        else
        {
            var scheduleInDb = _context.ScheduleBuilder.Single(a => a.Id == scheduleBuilder.Id);

            scheduleInDb.MondayStartTime = scheduleBuilder.MondayStartTime;
            scheduleInDb.TuesdayStartTime = scheduleBuilder.TuesdayStartTime;
            scheduleInDb.WednesdayStartTime = scheduleBuilder.WednesdayStartTime;
            scheduleInDb.ThursdayStartTime = scheduleBuilder.ThursdayStartTime;
            scheduleInDb.FridayStartTime = scheduleBuilder.FridayStartTime;
            scheduleInDb.SaturdayStartTime = scheduleBuilder.SaturdayStartTime;
            scheduleInDb.SundayStartTime = scheduleBuilder.SundayStartTime;

            scheduleInDb.MondayEndTime = scheduleBuilder.MondayEndTime;
            scheduleInDb.TuesdayEndTime = scheduleBuilder.TuesdayEndTime;
            scheduleInDb.WednesdayEndTime = scheduleBuilder.WednesdayEndTime;
            scheduleInDb.ThursdayEndTime = scheduleBuilder.ThursdayEndTime;
            scheduleInDb.FridayEndTime = scheduleBuilder.FridayEndTime;
            scheduleInDb.SaturdayEndTime = scheduleBuilder.SaturdayEndTime;
            scheduleInDb.SundayEndTime = scheduleBuilder.SundayEndTime;

            scheduleInDb.MondayFirstBreak = scheduleBuilder.MondayFirstBreak;
            scheduleInDb.TuesdayFirstBreak = scheduleBuilder.TuesdayFirstBreak;
            scheduleInDb.WednesdayFirstBreak = scheduleBuilder.WednesdayFirstBreak;
            scheduleInDb.ThursdayFirstBreak = scheduleBuilder.ThursdayFirstBreak;
            scheduleInDb.FridayFirstBreak = scheduleBuilder.FridayFirstBreak;
            scheduleInDb.SaturdayFirstBreak = scheduleBuilder.SaturdayFirstBreak;
            scheduleInDb.SundayFirstBreak = scheduleBuilder.SundayFirstBreak;

            scheduleInDb.MondaySecondBreak = scheduleBuilder.MondaySecondBreak;
            scheduleInDb.TuesdaySecondBreak = scheduleBuilder.TuesdaySecondBreak;
            scheduleInDb.WednesdaySecondBreak = scheduleBuilder.WednesdaySecondBreak;
            scheduleInDb.ThursdaySecondBreak = scheduleBuilder.ThursdaySecondBreak;
            scheduleInDb.FridaySecondBreak = scheduleBuilder.FridayFirstBreak;
            scheduleInDb.SaturdaySecondBreak = scheduleBuilder.SaturdaySecondBreak;
            scheduleInDb.SundaySecondBreak = scheduleBuilder.SundaySecondBreak;

            scheduleInDb.MondayLunch = scheduleBuilder.MondayLunch;
            scheduleInDb.TuesdayLunch = scheduleBuilder.TuesdayLunch;
            scheduleInDb.WednesdayLunch = scheduleBuilder.WednesdayLunch;
            scheduleInDb.ThursdayLunch = scheduleBuilder.ThursdayLunch;
            scheduleInDb.FridayLunch = scheduleBuilder.FridayLunch;
            scheduleInDb.SaturdayLunch = scheduleBuilder.SaturdayLunch;
            scheduleInDb.SundayLunch = scheduleBuilder.SundayLunch;

        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ScheduleBuilder", "Schedule");
    }
```

ViewModel

```
 public class TierViewModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<Tier> TierLevel { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ShiftLevel> ShiftLevel { get; set; }
        public ScheduleBuilder ScheduleBuilder { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ScheduleBuilder> ScheduleBuilderList { get; set; }
        public ScheduleBuilderTier2 ScheduleBuilderTwo { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show code how to assign `ScheduleBuilderList` on controller side? I think you can use LINQ `Select` with flag columns to find out which schedules are already assigned to other employees.

Comment: I added the ActionResult Save method above and included the rest of the Schedule Model. The controller method has a ton of conditionals for other purposes that works.  It just the hiding values in dropdown part I can't figure out.

Comment: I also added the ViewModel at the bottom for the ScheduleBuilderList if that's what you were asking for